# How to pattern match and transform string to generate certain output?

Tags: java, arrays, regex

The below code is for getting some form of input which includes lots of whitespace in between important strings and before and after the important strings, so far I have been able to filter the whitespace out. After preparing the string what I want to do is process it.

Here is an example of the inputs that I may get and the favorable output I want;

```
Input
+--------------+
                EDIT       example.mv                   Starter                                                 web-onyx-01.example.net.mv
```

Notice how whitespace id before and after the domain, this whitespace could be concluded as random amount.

```
Output
+--------------+

example.mv.            in      ns      web-onyx-01.example.net.mv.
```

In the output the important bit is the whitespace between the domain (Example.) and the keyword (in) and keyword (ns) and host (web-onyx-01.example.net.mv.) 
Also notice the period (".") after the domain and host. Another part is the fact that if its a (.mv) ccTLD we will have to remove that bit from the string,

What I would like to achieve is this transformation with multiple lines of text, meaning I want to process a bunch of unordered chaotic list of strings and batch process them to produce the clean looking outputs.

The code is by no-means any good design, but this is at least what I have come up with. NOTE: I am a beginner who is still learning about programming. I would like your suggestions to improve the code as well as to solve the problem at hand i.e transform the input to the desired output.

P.S The output is for zone files in DNS, so errors can be very problematic.

So far my code is accepting text from a textarea and outputs the text into another textarea which shows the output. 
My code works for as long as the array length is 2 and 3 but fails at anything larger. So how do I go about being able to process the input to the output dynamically for as big as the list/array may become in the future?

```
    String s = jTextArea1.getText();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ADD|EDIT|DELETE|Domain|Starter|Silver|Gold|ADSL Business|Pro|Lite|Standard|ADSL Multi|Pro Plus", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    s = m.replaceAll("");

   String ms = s.replaceAll("(?m)(^\\s+|[\\t\\f ](?=[\\t\\f ])|[\\t\\f ]$|\\s+\\z)", "");

   String[] last = ms.split(" ");
   for (String test : last){
       System.out.println(test);
   }
   System.out.println("The length of array is: " +last.length);

  if (str.isContain(last[0], ".mv")) {

     if (last.length == 2) {

            for(int i = 0; i < last.length; i++) {
                last[0] = last[0].replaceFirst(".mv", "");
                System.out.println(last[0]);
                last[i] += ".";
                if (last[i] == null ? last[0] == null : last[i].equals(last[0])) {

                    last[i]+= "            in      ns      ";
                }
            String str1 = String.join("", last);
            jTextArea2.setText(str1);
            System.out.println(str1);
            }

        }
     else if (last.length == 3) {
         for(int i = 0; i < last.length; i++) {
                last[0] = last[0].replaceFirst(".mv", "");
                System.out.println(last[0]);
                last[i] += ".";
                if (last[i] == null ? last[0] == null : last[i].equals(last[0])) {

                    last[i]+= "            in      ns      ";
                }
                if (last[i] == null ? last[1] == null : last[i].equals(last[1])){
                    last[i] += "\n";
                }
                if (last[i] == null ? last[2] == null : last[i].equals(last[2])){
                    last[i] = last[0] + last[2];
                }
            String str1 = String.join("", last);
            jTextArea2.setText(str1);
            System.out.println(str1);
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: "What I would like to achieve is this transformation with multiple lines of text, meaning I want to process a bunch of unordered chaotic list of strings and batch process them to produce the clean looking outputs." - while it's possible to guess what you're after some examples would make it way easier to understand and grasp possible edge cases (which should be included in the examples).

Comment: use String.format() may help you

Comment: @Thomas I am new to StackOverFlow so when I posted my question things were a bit messy but thanks to the people that edited.

An example of the input is in the question in a more clear format now and the output that I want is also there. I want to remove the whitespaces and some of the useless texts. Then I want to add some things to the final string that will be printed as the desired output. 

This is for zone file in DNS

Comment: The edited question is quite good, I just asked for a couple more examples (especially edge cases) for a better understanding. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question you have multiple lines of input in the following form:

```
whitespace[command]whitespace[domain]whitespace[label]whitespace[target-domain]whitespace
```

You want to convert that to the following form such that multiple lines are aligned nicely:

```
[domain].     in    ns     [target-domain].
```

To do that I'd suggest the following:

1. Split your input into multiple lines
2. Use a regular expression to check the line format (e.g. for a valid command etc.) and extract the domains
3. store the maximum length of both domains separately
4. build a string format using the maximum lengths
5. iterate over the extraced domains and build a string for that line using the format defined in step 4

Example:

```
 String input = "        EDIT        domain1.mv          Starter          example.domain1.net.mv     \n" +
               "        DELETE        long-domain1.mv          Silver          long-example.long-domain1.net.mv     \n" +
               "        ADD        short-domain1.mv          ADSL Business          ex.sdomain1.net.mv     \n";

//step 1: split the input into lines
String[] lines = input.split( "\n" );

//step 2: build a regular expression to check the line format and extract the domains - which are the (\S+) parts
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "^\\s*(?:ADD|EDIT|DELETE)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(?:Domain|Starter|Silver|Gold|ADSL Business|Pro|Lite|Standard|ADSL Multi|Pro Plus)\\s+(\\S+)\\s*$" );


List<String[]> lineList = new LinkedList<>();
int maxLengthDomain = 0;
int maxLengthTargetDomain = 0;

for( String line : lines )
{
  //step 2: check the line
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( line );
  if( matcher.matches() ) {
    //step 2: extract the domains
    String domain = matcher.group( 1 );
    String targetDomain = matcher.group( 2 );

    //step 3: get the maximum length of the domains
    maxLengthDomain = Math.max( maxLengthDomain, domain.length() );
    maxLengthTargetDomain = Math.max( maxLengthTargetDomain, targetDomain.length() );

    lineList.add( new String[] { domain, targetDomain } );
  }
}

//step 4: build the format string with variable lengths
String formatString = String.format( "%%-%ds in      ns   %%-%ds", maxLengthDomain + 5, maxLengthTargetDomain + 2 );

//step 5: build the output
for( String[] line : lineList ) {
  System.out.println( String.format( formatString, line[0] + ".", line[1] + "." ) );
}
```

Result:

```
domain1.mv.           in      ns   example.domain1.net.mv.           
long-domain1.mv.      in      ns   long-example.long-domain1.net.mv. 
short-domain1.mv.     in      ns   ex.sdomain1.net.mv.
```

Comment: This is actually quite the solution that I wanted, your walk through with the comments is really awesome thanks a bunch! I will figure out how to remove the ".mv" part as this is the only special case where I have to remove the TL which is also only from the domain and not the target domain(s). All other TLDs like ".com" or ".com.mv" remains unchanged. example: 
domain1.com.mv == domain1.com.mv.
domain1.com == domain.com.
domain1.mv == domain1.

Also I learned new stuff *never knew you could use array type as a generic*